# STL algorithm for Vector Add

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, stl, vectormath

Say I have two `vector<int>`s:

```
vector<int> foo{1, 2, 3};
vector<int> bar{10, 20, 30};
```

Now I want to do a vector add on them such that the result would be:

> 11
>   22
>   33

Is there an STL algorithm that will handle this, or do I need to use a `for` loop:

```
for(auto i = 0; i < foo.size(); ++i){
    foo[i] += bar[i];
}
```

Bonus question, what if I wanted to do something more complicated than an add, say `foo` was a `vector<string>` and `bar` was still a `vector<int>`. I'm hoping that, if there is an STL algorithm I can use, it would also support lambdas?

Comment: Templated operator overloading?

Comment: @GregAnkit No, I am not trying to come up with my own operators, I just need an STL algorithm which will perform a function taking in the corresponding elements of two vectors and assigning the value back to one of them.

Comment: @GargAnkit Incidentally there is a question about overloading `vector`'s operators though, if you're interested: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6366231/2642059

Answer (score 21, accepted):

What you want to do can be achieved using [`std::transform`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform).
In your case:

```
std::transform(foo.begin(), foo.end(), bar.begin(), foo.begin(), std::plus<int>());
```

`std::transform` does support lambdas as well so you can do more complicated operations between `vector` elements.

Comment: I feel kinda silly now, I thought `std::transform` only had a unary operation format.

Comment: I have an amateurish question: What is happening deep inside, is still a loop, am I right?

Comment: @Pouya Probably, the standard does not specify how STL algorithms must be implemented by compilers, so in the future they might use multiple cores to implement this or who knows what. Which is one of the reasons it's better to use STL algorithms than your own loops. But for now, yeah it's probably just a loop. That's the suggested implementation of cplusplus.com anyway: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/transform/

Comment: For this actual case, there is a realistic chance of the vectorizer spotting the loop and replacing it with a vectorized version. Not that this would improve your N=3 case, but it would help for N=3000.